# Adding client side function onclick of kendo grid row Edit

Tags: kendo-grid

I am using a kendo grid in my project. And I have the Edit mode inline there.
So each row having an Edit button.
I want to add a client side function on click of the Edit button. How to do ?
Here is my code for creating Edit button.

```
 var editColumn = {
                command: ["edit"], title: "", width: 150
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created the following [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/aqAqe) to get you up and running with binding to the edit event of the grid.

All I am doing is adding the currently selected model to a `pre` tag so it shows you the data is being called.

all I have had to do is add the `edit:onEdit` declaration (**onEdit** can be any function you want)

If you need more info then feel free to update the question